# FullCalendar shown multiple time

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, fullcalendar

I have multiple pages in my application. I create Calendar using jquery mobile fullCalendar.js framework. Now my problem is that, when I click on any back button of my application pages and back to calendar pages calendar is repeated.

Comment: Are your multiple pages part of the same HTML page or separate pages? How are you creating your calendar (what event)? Most likely your issue is due to the page being cached in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are calling **fullCalendar** function on DOM Ready then after the call you will have a basic html structure somewhat like this:

```
<div id="myCalendar" class="fc">
    <table style="width:100%; margin-bottom:20px" class="fc-header">
    </table>
    <div class="fc-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then what you can simply do is, before the **fullCalendar** call introduce a predicate like this:

```
if ($('.fc').find('.fc-content').length <= 0)
   console.log('call .fullCalendar()');
else
   console.log('dont do anything');
```

Hopefully this will work for you.